# Is using "general plan of structure" appropriate in biology?

Tags: meaning-in-context, style, formality

I'm reading now a book (which was written by a non-native English speaker) that states under the title of the topic:

> "general plan of structure of the digestive tube"

The chapter there explains and describes the structure of the digestive system, and I think that the using of "**plan**" is relevant for buildings rather than anatomy. Isn't it?

Is it acceptable to use "plan" in this context, or it's a mistake?

Comment: I can't tell whether "plan of structure" is a term of art or merely an awkward phrasing. Assuming it means anything cogent, and is not a term of art, I would prefer to phrase it "general plan of **the** structure of **the** digestive tube" ... otherwise it sounds like it was written by a native Russian speaker or some other non-native.

Comment: I agree with Robusto here. Generally, a non-native speaker would get their technical terms right, but to write like a native speaker in terms of grammar and style is much, much harder.

Comment: That's true it was written by a native Russian speaker. Nice guessing. but I forgot to put one article which was in the original sentence.

Comment: "Plan" is commonly used in this context; see, e.g. _"...two-legged (bipedal) posture, a fact that has greatly modified the general mammalian body plan."_ ([Encyclopædia Brittanica](https://www.britannica.com/science/human-body))

Comment: _"General plan of structure of the digestive tube"_ is a perfectly idiomatic and expected topic heading in a work on anatomy. It wouldn't be out of place in any such text written by a native English speaker.

Comment: but actually it means the same meaning as the sentence "general structure of the digestive tube" means?

Comment: No, not really. _Structure_ refers to the physical components of a design. _Plan_ refers to the design itself. You should read some anatomy/medical texts in English (or the article I linked to above) to see how _plan_ is used in medicine and science. Your author is not mistaken. He uses _plan_ intentionally because he knows what he's doing. For example, this citation for _plan_ from OED: _1995   New Scientist 16 Dec. 17/1..."A phylum is a group of creatures which share a distinct body plan."_

Comment: Thank you for the explanation but I have to admire that I still don't understand the difference/s.

Comment: @Assiduous Any good dictionary provides definitions of both words, and when you understand those definitions, you will see that _structure_ and _plan_ are specific and different things. A _structure_ in medicine is, e.g., the [**structure of the spleen.**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spleen#Structure). A _plan_ in this context is the general _anatomical design_ of the organism or system within an organism, e.g. [**fish**.](http://81832.com/images/plan-alimentary-canal.png)

Comment: I think if you included the sentences which came before and after the sentence in question, you'd probably get users to post answers instead of comments. And could you please include a link, if there is one, the title of the book, and the name of the author.

Comment: This sounds suspiciously like un plan général. Un plan is a drawing. This is from French. The diagram of the digestive tube's structure.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, using "plan" (or "design") is acceptable in biology. Perhaps an anti-theist would object on the basis of there being no planner.  But that is like objecting to the use of the word "creature", implying that it is a created thing. If it makes one feel better, think of the "plan" as being the inevitable result of natural selection. (I do not know of the OP is anti-theist or not. This is only trying to explain why "plan" is not unacceptable.)

I would phrase the topic title differently.

- General Structural Plan of the Digestive Tube

The phrase "general structure" would describe *what* is there, and *where*.  "General structural plan" describes *what*, *where*, *why*, and *how*.

Answer (score 0):

It is appropriate to use "plan" here, but it looks slightly odd to me as a native speaker and holder of a B.S. in Biology *in this specific context*. As noted in comments, phrases like "mammalian body plan" are not only common but are the accepted scientific terms across the field and especially in anatomy. "Design" is commonly used in this context in the field (in my experience and observation, but I have never focused on anatomy or physiology, where this usage of "plan" is standard).

Outside of anatomy and physiology, a plan generally implies intent from a planner making decisions in advance to support some specific outcome. Similarly, a design implies a designer but the implication is less strong than with plan. Scattering paint randomly across a canvas might produce a pleasing *design*, but would never produce a *plan*, despite the actual result being neither planned nor designed.

Evolution operates on existing structures or processes and favors certain changes over others in different environments, leading (in very, very general terms) to structures that are effectively designed to operate in a specific way (or ways) for a specific purpose (or purposes). When there is a single structure, like a digestive tube, that has (essentially) a single variant, it is "designed" in the sense that evolutionary pressures favored that one variant and not others. But this is an unguided process that does not require intelligence or intent.

In summary, a biological structure *has* a plan/design that describes its actual structure: what components it has, where they are, how they operate together, etc. You can describe a biological structure as *being designed* or *having been designed*, such as for a particular purpose, but trying to describe that same structure as *being planned* or *having been planned* for that same purpose would sound odd. If you are using "plan" in this field as a noun, you may be (and probably are) using it correctly. Using "plan" as a verb in this field is probably incorrect.

Comment: General plan is a translation from French. It is most likely not English at all....